# Is it possible to pass just a String as the data-model for a FreeMarker template?

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to use pass to a FreeMarker template just one variable, i.e. some text, e.g. `"this is a text"`; is it possible to pass one `String` only as the *model* variable instead of packing it into an object or a Map? What would look like the `FreeMarker` template using the `String` variable?

PS: should work with Java

Comment: I wrote a super simple [example](https://github.com/paolopiccinini/openhtmltopdf-example) while using freemarker with openHtmlToPdf. Hope this helps

Comment: Your example is using a `HashMap` for the *model* variable instead of a `String`!

Comment: Have you read the doc?: `dataModel - the holder of the variables visible from the template (name-value pairs); usually a Map<String, Object> or a JavaBean (where the JavaBean properties will be the variables). Can be any object that the ObjectWrapper in use turns into a TemplateHashModel. You can also use an object that already implements TemplateHashModel; in that case it won't be wrapped. If it's null, an empty data model is used.` I don't think you can use a String anyway, maybe a JaveBean with a String in it

Comment: Tryed with a String : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: freemarker.template.DefaultObjectWrapper didn't convert java.lang.String to a TemplateHashModel. Generally, you want to use a Map<String, Object> or a JavaBean as the root-map (aka. data-model) parameter. The Map key-s or JavaBean property names will be the variable names in the template.` I've pushed look at FreeMarkerExample2.java, you can use a JavaBean instead as in the example

Comment: Yes, I read it and I only hoped for a hack someone might know.

Comment: You can’t even extend String and then implement TemplateHashModel. String is final so there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

The variables exposed to the template must have a name. Even if you only have one variable. How would you refer to that value in the template otherwise? Like `Hello ${whatWillBeHere}!`?

Comment: well, your question is the post's question, right? My question: "What would look like the FreeMarker template using the String variable?"

Comment: Ah, I read this too fast, and skipped the last sentence somehow. Anyway, now you know that you must specify a name. There's no default name or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on my own experience confirmed here in the comments I conclude that the answer is: it is not possible to pass one `String` only as the *model* variable instead of packing it into an object or a `Map`.